# The decision tree has height at least $\log n!$

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, trees, sorting

The proof of the theorem

> Any decision tree that sorts $n$ distinct elements has height at least $\log n!$

is the following:

Since the result of sorting $n$ elements can be any one of the $n!$ permutations of the input, there must be at least $n!$ leaves in the decision tree.

By the lemma:

> A binary tree of height $h$ has at most $2^h$ leaves.

the height must be at least $\log n!$.

$$$$

At the lemma we have thast a binary tree of height $h$ has **at most**
$2^{h}$ leaves, how do we get at the proof of the theorem **at least** ??

Comment: can't you use a hash table and sort them in constant time.

Comment: @user45195 Incorrect (linear time != constant time) and irrelevant (a hash function won't be described by a constant-height decision tree).

Comment: The number of items is not specified, so a hash table works better for larger amounts of data, even if it is linear time (constant time was my mistake). Isn't it more optimal in the long run?

Comment: @user45195 Notice the question does not ask for the best way to sort a list :).  The whole point of the OP is to show that a decision tree cannot sort faster than $O(n \log n)$.  Whether or not it can be done faster by other means is irrelevant to the question at hand.  (And I'm skeptical that a hash table would be of much value, since it wouldn't generically preserve sort order.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to distinguish $n!$ outcomes, and you need at least one leaf for each thing that you distinguish, so you need at least $n!$ leaves; this has nothing to do with the lemma. The lemma comes into play at the next step: if the height were less than $\lg n!$, the tree would have fewer than $n!$ leaves, so it must have height at least $\lg n!$.

**Added:** To see one reason that you might have more than $n!$ leaves, consider the following decision procedure for sorting three items, $a,b$, and $c$, by weight: weigh $a$ against $b$, then $a$ against $c$, and finally $b$ against $c$. Here’s half of the decision tree:

```
                                                                     / abc  
                                                                b<c /  
                                                            _______/  
                                                           /       \  
                                                      a<c /     c<b \  
                                                         /           \ acb  
                                         _______________/  
                                        /               \               
                                       /                 \           / impossible
                                      /               c<a \     b<c /  
                                     /                     \_______/  
                                a<b /                              \  
                                   /                            c<b \  
                                  /                                  \ cab  
                                 /  
                                 \  
                                  \ This will be the b<a side of the tree.  
                                    From the top down, it will have leaves 
                                    bac, impossible, bca, and cba.
```

In this case two of the leaves will never be reached, because they correspond to impossible situations, but they’re still part of the tree. (There are of course better sorting procedures!)

Comment: Could you explain me further why we need at least $n!$ leaves??

Comment: @Mary: There are $n!$ possible sorted orders of the $n$ items, so your decision tree has to allow for $n!$ different possible outcomes. Each leaf is one outcome, the result of a particular sequence of decisions, so you need at least $n!$ leaves. It’s *at least* instead of *exactly* because a given sorted order might be the result of more than one sequence of decisions, in which case it would correspond to more than one leaf, and you would then have more than $n!$ leaves.

Comment: I haven`t understood why it is at least and not exactly... Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: @Mary: I couldn’t quickly come up with an example of the kind that I mentioned in the previous comment, but I did add an example of a different kind to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because

> A binary tree of height $h$ has at most $2^h$ leaves.

implies

> A binary tree with at least $2^h$ leaves has a height at least $h$.

Comment: Could you explain me further the implication??

Comment: The decision tree must have $n!$ leaves, right? So, from the implication it follows that a binary tree with at least $n! = 2^{\log_2 n!}$ leaves must have a height at least $\log_2 n!$.